# Angular 11 - subscribe does not return correct data for response type text

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor, content-type, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I have a weird problem. I hope I would be able to explain.

I am encrypting something in the backend and API response returns a plain string in encrypted format something like this:

```
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
```

Now, in the Angular client, I have decryption logic that converts the above code to a JSON response which I will need to show in the UI.

As I need to filter specific APIS for decryption, I am modifying response in the interceptor like this:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && request.url.search('/decryptAPI') !== -1) {
          event = event.clone({body: this.modifyBody(request, event.body)});
          console.log('event', event);
        }
        return event;
    }));

private modifyBody(request: any, response: any): any {
    console.log('request URL', request.url);
    const data = decryptBackendResponse(response);
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
```

But the service which I use for the HTTP call for this is like this:

```
getWithText(url: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    return this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

All fine till now, but once I modify the code, and one component subscribes to it, I get the error in console:

```
error Error: Response is not a string.
at MapSubscriber.project (http.js:1122)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

I think the issue is because the HTTP response type is the text that's the reason subscribe is failing while decrypted content it is getting is JSON.

If I change getWithText() response to JSON, the interceptor HTTP call itself will fail because the response type is an encrypted string.

How do I solve this proble? Is there any way, I can make my subscribe code works by accepting JSON response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely you also need to modify the response type header sent by the server

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm It is text only as the response is an encrypted string. When I subscribe to data in a component, how can I accept it as JSON if I have modified it in interceptor from encrypted text to decrypted JSON?